# sql server output charset

Tags: php, sql-server, database, encoding, character-encoding

Is there any way to get **MSSQL Server** result in charset different from the native database encoding?

I mean something like "*set names*" which is used by *MySQL*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the column type of your data? Is it varchar or nvarchar?

To get results in Unicode, simply cast varchar columns as nvarchar:
SELECT CAST(Column AS nvarchar(size)) FROM Table

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on a per column basis

```
SELECT COLUMN Collate CollationName
From Table
```

Comment: Thank you for response; I didn't found utf-8 Collation. I passed a lot of discussions about that there is no utf-8 support on < mssql 08. ???